# Get misclassified samples from validation set using index and form a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, confusion-matrix

Hi I have a `confusion matrix` and I need to fetch `misclassified samples` from it and form a `dataframe` with columns `[samples,actual,predicted]`.

I have done the follwing:

```
misclassified = np.where(y_test_class!= y_pred_class)
```

Where `y_test_class` is the actual classes and `y_pred_class` is the predicted.Now to find the corresponding samples and classes, I used

```
mis_np = np.concatenate(X_test[misclassified],y_test_class[misclassified],y_pred[misclassified])
mis_df = pd.DataFrame(mis_np)
```

But I get the error

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
>   index

Comment: Are you trying to make a dataframe of 3 columns, `X, y_true, y_pred`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
mis_np = np.concatenate(
    (X_test[misclassified],y_test_class[misclassified],y_pred[misclassified]), 
    axis=1
)

mis_df = pd.DataFrame(data=mis_np, columns=['X', 'y_true', 'y_pred'])
```

Note that the first argument of `np.concatenate` should be a sequence of arrays.

So you just wrap your arrays in a tuple. Also set `axis=1` to create 2D array (matrix).